# Can I add JavaDoc to a package easily with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I use javadoc to document my classes and methods. I would like to add some overview information to my packages, too. I like how Eclipse creates a stub of a matching Doc Comment for each class or method once I type `/**<Enter>`. Does Eclipse have an easy way to generate a [package.html file](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/writingdoccomments/index.html#packagecomments), too?

Comment: Just a note: as of Java 1.5, the preferred location for package comments is package-info.java, not package.html. This way, it is also possible to define package-level annotations. See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/whatsnew-1.5.0.html

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Update 4 years later (Oct. 2013)

[javabeangrinder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1782954/javabeangrinder)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14708381/6309) (upvoted) mentions the following trick:

> To create a `package-info.java` file in an existing package:

- Right click on the package where you want a `package-info.java`.
- Select `new->package`.
- Check the `Create package.info.java` check box.
- Click on `Finish`

---

Original answer (May 2009)

There is no template or wizard to easily create a package.html file.

As [mmyers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13531/mmyers) said in his comment, since `Java1.5`, the correct file to create would be [`package-info.java`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/whatsnew-1.5.0.html).
That file can be used not only for javadocs, but also for [package-level annotations](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/04/21/declarative.html?page=3) (as [illustrated here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/09/using_jaxb_20s.html)).

There is an [opened Bug (#86168)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=86168) for demanding a wizard for the creation of `package-info.java` (since **the class wizard does not allow the `package-info` name**).

The reflections on that topic are on since... 2005! The problem is that any solution should
be implemented in a way that it also helps with `1.4` code.

The current workaround is to create a `package-info.java` as a `text` file.
From that point forward, `package-info.java` behaves as a normal Java class, and Eclipse places a `package-info.class` file in the output folder.
The `Javadocs` are correctly built using `package-info.java`, and not the `package.html` file.

[image]
<sub>(source: [developpez.com](http://jmdoudoux.developpez.com/cours/developpons/java/images/jaxb006.png))</sub>

---

Note (in response to [Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187492/strawberry)'s comment):

- [bug 77451](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=77451) (2004!, for package.html)
- [bug 163633](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=163633) and [bug 163926](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=163926)  (2006, for package-info.java)

both ***wish*** a **preview of the package overview in package-info.java in the Javadoc
view**.

So far, no patch has been proposed/implemented.
There is simply not enough demands for that feature to be added.

Comment: Is there anyway to get the package javadocs to show in the Javadoc fast view window - as they do for classes, interfaces and methods?

Comment: @Strawberry: nope, no Javadoc view for package-info.java. See my extended answer on that.

Comment: Note to self, after [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9600531/6309), I got to cross over 200K *again*! (due to some [rep recalc](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125121/has-reputation-for-deleted-posts-been-removed-again))

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Good solution indeed. I have included it and notified his author.

Answer (score 15):

**In eclipse**

Since package-info.java isn't a valid identifier for a class it cannot be created as a class in Eclipse.

I found that when you create a new package there is a check box to check if you want a package-info.java.

To create a package-info.java file in an existing package:

1. Right click on the package where you want a package-info.java.
2. Select new->package.
3. Check the Create package.info.java check box.
4. Click on Finish

Comment: Haha that's so intuitive, thanks :) It doesn't answer the question, but it helped me!

Comment: In Kepler the checkbox now says "Create package-info.java". Believe it or not, the lack of the hyphen in step 3 above confused me slightly.

Comment: On Luna, it won't let me do this without specifying a new package name.

Answer (score 13):

The **JAutodoc** plugin does a great job of this, as well as all your other documentation needs. Install and configure the plugin and right click the package and click *JAutodoc > Add Package Javadoc*

There are configurations and templates available for the `.java` or `.html` package documentation.

This plugin also does a great job of standardizing all your Javadoc needs, with a great deal of customization.

http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

There's a plugin that seems to create package.html files.  I haven't used it but someone landing here might find it useful.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/package-javadoc/