# Javadoc: package.html or package-info.java

Tags: java, javadoc

When trying to create package level Javadoc comments, whats the preferred method? What do you do?

**package-info.java**

- Pros

  - Newer
- Cons

  - Abuse of a class - Classes are for code, not for only comments

**package.html**

- Pros

  - HTML extension means its not code
  - Syntax highlighting in IDE's/text editors
- Cons

  - None?

---

For me, I've always used Package.html. But I'm wondering if its the correct choice.

Comment: `package-info.java` can contain [package] annotations - it's not necessarily all API docs.

Comment: I wouldn't qualify package-info.java as an abuse of a class.  It's a java source file (has a ".java" file extension) but is not a class file because it does not contain a class declaration. And, in fact, it can not contain a class declaration because "package-info" is not a legal class name.

Comment: Another reason for using package-info.java instead of package.html could be that .java does not imply a specific output format of the documentation. For example you might want to output the javadoc as LaTeX or as a PDF file. Depending of javadoc compiler implementation this could cause problems in the .html case.

Comment: Actually @Scrubbie - although you should be right, I think you can specify package-private classes in there. :-( I agree with your sentiment though, using `package-info.java` for Javadoc and Annotations is not an abuse of a class.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Eclipse, I can't find a way to bring up the Javadoc view for a package-info.java I made... :( There seems to be nothing that can be recognized as the 'thing' that the Javadoc is attached to.

Comment: @JonasN see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14708381/751579 (I know you had this problem 3 years ago, but maybe someone else needs the tip now)

Comment: Package-info.java contents appear on Eclipse in a small window when we pass the mouse over each package name. eg: {{ package org.test.jobs.timecontrol }}. A different contents will appear for each word.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

`package-info.java`: "This file is new in JDK 5.0, and is preferred over package.html."—[*javadoc - The Java API Documentation Generator*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html#packagecomment)

Addendum: The big difference seems to be *package annotations*. There's a little more in the way of rationale in [*7.4 Package Declarations*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4).

Addendum: The annotation feature is also mentioned [here](http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/02/28/package-annotations/) and in [*Javadoc tip: Prefer package-info to package.html*](https://web.archive.org/web/20080204050234/http://blogs.sun.com/darcy/entry/javadoc_tip_prefer_package_info), cited [here](https://github.com/jddarcy/BlogsSunComArchive#2006).

Addendum: See also [*What’s `package-info.java` for?*](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/whats-package-info-java-for/).

Comment: Any particular reason why its preferred?

Comment: @TheLQ: I'm guessing package annotations, as the compiler has more information to work with; more above.

Comment: Package annotations are new to me, and seem a good reason for package-info.java due to its scope.

Comment: Edit answer just a bit more:  explain "package annotation"  --  an annotation which is to be applied to all of the classes in a package or otherwise to the packages as a whole.  The tech.puredanger.com link was the only one to really explain why I should care.  That said, it's a good, helpful link.

Comment: using package-info.java you can use {@link } and other doclets. When you link a java.lang class, when javadoc is generated you automatically get the {@link } pointing to the online javadoc of the class matching the jdk you are using; ide can also help to spot wrong links when you do refactoring refactoring.

Comment: You can also apply package metadata like JaxB's @XmlSchema with package-info.java.