# Package not found or wo package-info.java

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss7.x

```
WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] HHH00194:Package not found or wo package-info.java: com.mycompany.myapp.mypackage
```

I get this WARNing message during deployment of my hibernate app on JBoss 7.  I'm still able to deploy successfully, and hibernate works.  But I'd like to eliminate these WARN message at startup.

I tried placing a package-info.java file at the root of my package directory.  So, in src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/mypackage I have a package-info.java file that looks like

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.mypackage;
```

This did not fix the problem.  Am I doing the right thing?  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Are you using a logging utility? Could you just change the logging level?

Comment: Logging is already at TRACE level

Comment: It's at DEBUG as of Hibernate 4.0.0.Final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is addressed in the JBoss forum here:
http://community.jboss.org/message/622023#622023

Comment: And the stamenent on the forums is that this is nothing to worry about. In future versions the message will be displayed as debug instead of warning.

Answer (score 0):

did you fill the package-info.java as described in  [java documentation here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#packagecomment)? In particular, it requires that *the comment separators `/**` and `/*` must be present* ie the minimum requirement for file seems to be like:

```
    /**
     * Not sure if this line is necessary but ones above and below are.
     */
    package com.mycompany.myapp.mypackage; // case sensitive correct package name
```

This was also discussed in [How to add package level comments in Javadoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650907/how-to-add-package-level-comments)

I ask because per my recollection, javadoc sometimes "refused" to generate package info in cases when particular *rules* like I refer to above were broken. That may explain why you're still getting warnings even though file is there. Check in particular if package is defined correctly in your file.

- As a reference, structure of source code for [java.lang package-info.java in JDK 6](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/annotate/2e29fe2bfc9c/src/share/classes/java/lang/package-info.java) looks about as follows:

  ```
  /* ... lengthy copyright... */

  /**
   * Provides classes that are fundamental to the design of the Java
   * ...
   */
  package java.lang;
  ```

Comment: Package name is correct.  I don't have any comments to add - should i just add empty /** */ comments?  I'm not sure what comments has to do with it

Comment: I updated the answer wrt `/** */`. If you find this still doesn't get you there, re-check the doc for there may be more requirements

Answer (score 0):

As @Riggs mentioned it in his link, the next Hibernate version would be trace this messages as DEBUG, no more WARN.

If I were you I would not worry too much about it (unless you have time to create a bunch of package-info.java :)