# how to create package-info.java file in netbeans?

Tags: java

can any body please tell me how to create package-info.java file in netbeans,when  i am trying to create a new java file with name package-info to specify a package level annotation,class name is not valid error is thrown

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is possible to create such a file in NetBeans, ever since this bug https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60949 was fixed.

Answer (score 8):

The package-info.java is not exactly a java source file.

The proper way is, when you create a new file, do not create a Java Class file.
Instead, create a Java Package Info file, also in the Java category.
This will trigger the New Java Package Info wizard.

[image]

Comment: Choose `Tools > Templates > Open in Editor` to verify correct documentation comment syntax, `/**…*/`, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3644733/230513); some versions generate a traditional comment, `/*…*/`, which the doclet ignores.

Answer (score 5):

That's not completely correct. You can create a file under Other > Other > Empty File with name package-info.java

You can place there the Javadoc comments for the package and the "package" line:

```
/**
 * Here are some comments about this package.
 * Here is a comment linking to {@link java.lang.Object}.
 */
package packagename;
```