# JMapViewer add mouse listener to MapMarkerDot

Tags: java, mouseover, jmapviewer

I am trying to add a mouse listener to a MapMarker, so that when a mouse will hover a MapMarker, I could react with an event.

I implemented the mouseListener, but I can't really add a listener. 
The issue is that I did not find a way the MapMarker will addMouseListener, due to the fact that non of the hierarchy implements JPanel.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Reading the answer you posted there, it is duplicated. Thanks!

Comment: You can add it as an answer and I will approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14016425/230513), the default `JMapViewer` constructor uses a `DefaultMapController`, "which implements map moving by pressing the right mouse button and zooming by double click or by mouse wheel." To see map coordinates, extend `DefaultMapController`, override `mouseClicked()` and use one of the viewer's `getPosition()` methods. You can use your controller as shown in comments at line 65 of `Demo.java`, r30377.

```
 new DefaultMapController(map){

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(map.getPosition(e.getPoint()));
    }
};
```