# Using the mouseClicked method in the JMapViewer does not update the getPosition return value

Tags: java, coordinates, mouselistener, mouseclick-event, jmapviewer

I have create a MouseInputAdapter listener to get coordinates in a JMapViewer map and create the MapMarker on that spot but even though I click on a different possition the value of the map.getPossition() method does not updates with the new values.

My listener code:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
    Coordinate markeradd = map.getPosition();
    System.out.println(map.getPosition());
    map.addMapMarker(new MapMarkerDot(markeradd));
}
```

The system.out.print is there to print the value returned by the getPosition().
When I click for the first time, I get a set of coordinates then wherever I click, I always get the same coordinates.
example of five different position clicks:

```
Coordinate[56.159963018590744, 10.199775695800781]
Coordinate[56.159963018590744, 10.199775695800781]
Coordinate[56.159963018590744, 10.199775695800781]
Coordinate[56.159963018590744, 10.199775695800781]
Coordinate[56.159963018590744, 10.199775695800781]
```

Comment: I found out what happened. The map.getPosition() was always pointing to the centrer of the map even though the mouse was clicked in different positions on the map.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24588492/230513).

Comment: I saw the post that you mark as possible duplicate before I post the question. It didn't solve the problem, I had!

Comment: I've elaborated below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have observed, `getPosition()` "Calculates the latitude/longitude coordinate of the center of the currently displayed map area." You probably want

```
Coordinate getPosition(java.awt.Point mapPoint)
```

which "Converts the relative pixel coordinate … into a latitude / longitude coordinate." You can call it in your implementation of `JMapController`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24688091/230513) for a subclass of `DefaultMapController`.

```
new DefaultMapController(map) {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(map.getPosition(e.getPoint()));
    }
};
```