# how to create class file for a java file which has only package statement and annotations?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a file which has only two statements in it

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "XXXXX", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package sample;
```

want to create class file which has same name as filename is Package-info.java

Comment: That isn't a legal Java source file. It doesn't contain a class, so it can't produce a .class file.

Comment: Can you provide some context please? Where did you encounter this file? What is your actual objective? Package-info.java does not seem like the name of a Java class file.

Comment: package-info.java (note the lower case "p") is valid in Java 1.5 and beyond. However, package-info is an invalid class name (hyphens are disallowed in class names), so you **cannot** create a valid .class file with that name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javadoc: package.html or package-info.java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644726/javadoc-package-html-or-package-info-java)

Comment: @EJP : It is legal java source File and yes its my mistake file name is package-info.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`package-info.java` is not meant to be compilable. It is used by javadoc.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#packagecomment for more info:

Package Comment Files

Each package can have its own documentation comment, contained in its own "source" file, that the Javadoc tool will merge into the package summary page that it generates. You typically include in this comment any documentation that applies to the entire package.

To create a package comment file, you have a choice of two files to place your comments:

- package-info.java - Can contain a package declaration, package annotations, package comments and Javadoc tags. This file is generally preferred over package.html.
- package.html - Can contain only package comments and Javadoc tags, no package annotations.

A package may have a single package.html file or a single package-info.java file but not both. Place either file in the package directory in the source tree along with your .java files.

package-info.java - This file can contain a package comment of the following structure -- the comment is placed before the package declaration:

File: java/applet/package-info.java

```
/**
 * Provides the classes necessary to create an  
 * applet and the classes an applet uses 
 * to communicate with its applet context.
 * <p>
 * The applet framework involves two entities:
 * the applet and the applet context.
 * An applet is an embeddable window (see the
 * {@link java.awt.Panel} class) with a few extra
 * methods that the applet context can use to 
 * initialize, start, and stop the applet.
 *
 * @since 1.0
 * @see java.awt
 */
package java.lang.applet;
```