# What are all the steps to migrate from Base clearcase to UCM?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We have to migrate from base clearcase to UCM.

We have to move our Vobs from Base clearcase to Clearcase UCM.

Few of the steps were suggested by other teams.

1. Create PVOB
2. Create Project under it

Then they asked to move all the VOBs. Can we simply mount base clearcase vobs to UCM?

Or is it better to create UCM vob and move all the elements from base clearcase?

If any post or step by step guidance available to migrate from base clearcase to UCM, it would be helpful.

Some body please suggest the steps to be followed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite easy (for the ClearCase setup. I won't address the UCM training part, which is not relevant to your question).
You don't have to move the vobs.
There is no such thing as "mount base clearcase vobs to UCM" or "UCM Vob".
A Vob can contains elements managed by base ClearCase, and UCM component at the same time.

The only constraint you need to be aware is that **an UCM component has its root directly one level below the vob**:

```
aVob\aCmp1
aVob\aCmp2
...
```

So, **as long as all your future UCM components have their elements already** (in your current base ClearCase config) **in the first directory of a Vob**, you can:

- define UCM component `Cmp1` at any time, with its root directory at `\aVob\aCmp1`
- **go on using base ClearCase if you want** (it doesn't matter, and you will be able to merge your non-UCM branches with UCM ones): a parallel run is possible between base ClearCase usage and UCM usage.
- start using the newly defined components in an UCM project, making new versions in UCM branches (ie branches attached to Streams).

The PVob will be there to record your projects, Streams, and component definitions.

---

The [OP Samselvaprabu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399145/samselvaprabu)  adds in the comments:

> How to move all the files and directories from base to UCM. Should we copy, paste from Base to UCM and check-in all(using clearfsimport) or Clearcase itself has some nice ways to move the contents from base to UCM?

Short answer? **You do not "move to UCM"**:

(longer answer)
The only "move" you make is to make sure your data are organize under the first level of a Vob.
That means simple "`cleartool move`" of your data within a Vob.
No `clearfsimport` or any UCM commands required.

If you had some set of files you wish to declare as a component, and were stored in `\myVob\my_projects\p1`, just move `p1` (which will keep all its history) under `\myVob`: `\myVob\p1`.
That's it.
Nothing more to do.

Then, once your data are correctly organized, you just:

- go on using them in base ClearCase for as long as you want
- *while* declaring an UCM component, with a root directory at `\myVob\p1`.

When a component is declared, the only limitation is that you won't be able to move elements within `p1` outside of `\myVob\p1`.
But you can still move them, checkout and checkin them freely within `\myVob\p1`.
From base ClearCase views, or from UCM views.
Having a component declared at `\myVob\p1` doesn't include any other special limitations on the elements within that root directory. They aren't "transformed", keep their history, and can be used in base or in UCM at will.

Comment: Buddy, I want little bit more explanation towards elements movement. How to move all the files and directories from base to UCM. Should we copy, paste from Base to UCM and check-in all(using clearfsimport) or Clearcase itself has some nice ways to move the contents from base to UCM?

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: I have edited my answer to address your additional question.

Comment: Congrats buddy. Wishes you to write a book on UCM question and answer.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: well, if I don't write a book, I will have at least managed to write quite a lot here on Stack Overflow ;) Note that I would be more interested to write on Git: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/topusers