# I have a UCM component on a base CC vob, but cannot see it from a base CC view

Tags: clearcase-ucm

Here is my layout:

```
base CC vob name: vobs/sbftest
UCM vob name: vobs/P_sbftest
```

Vobadmin created a default "`Source`" component for my UCM vob that looks like this:

```
vobs/P_sbftest/Source
```

Vobadmin also created a project for my UCM vob:
so my project explorer looks like this:

[image: Project Explorer]

I added files to "Source" component through a remote client window.
Up to here all works find.

However, some of my team members will prefer to work under base CC, so according to this:
[What are all the steps to migrate from Base clearcase to UCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600322/what-are-all-the-steps-to-migrate-from-base-clearcase-to-ucm)

Base CC views should be able to see my `Source` component, and the files that it contains, but this is not the case in my situation.
I created a base CC view and it shows other folders created directly in the base CC view, but the view does not see the "Source" component folder created by the UCM view.

Am I missing something?
Shouldn't the base CC view be able to see the "Source" components?

Here are the specs of the base CC view:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/LATEST
load \sbftest
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using UCM, ClearCase will create branches named after your Stream name.
So, you need to add a selection rule which will select the versions added to your Stream:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT 
element * .../sbfuser_testir_proj_dev_strm/LATEST
element * .../am_testir_proj_dev_strm/LASTEST
element * .../testir_proj_int_strm/LASTEST
element * /main/LATEST 
load \sbftest
```

Note the '`.../branchname/LATEST`' syntax which means: select the `LATEST` versions of the branch '`branchname`', whatever the parent branch is.

I am not sure under which Stream you added your files, so the above config spec will select first the versions of branch '`sbfuser_testir_proj_dev_strm`'.
If there is no version in that branch, it will default to the `LATEST` versions in branch '`am_testir_proj_dev_strm`'.
If there is no version in that dev branch, it will default to the `LATEST` of the integration branch.

---

The [OP falconk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1179677/falconk) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487501/i-have-a-ucm-component-on-a-base-cc-vob-but-cannot-see-it-from-a-base-cc-view/12487697#comment17172227_12487697):

> I asked around here and it looks like the UCM component was not created with the right options

That would explain the issue, since the only option when creating a component (see [`cleartool mkcomp`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkcomp.htm)) is the `-root` one: a component is either a "root-based" or "rootless".
If that component has no root, it is a "meta-component" made to aggregate other components.
And no amount of config spec selection rules will allow for "`Source`" to be seen.

Comment: VonC, Thank you for your answer.  It looks great.  However I still can't see the "Source" component and its child folders (created through the UCM view alfredom_sbfuser_testir_proj_dev_view, stream: sbfuser_testir_proj_dev_stream).

Comment: @falconK What does a '`cleartool ls`' returns when you are in the root directory of that base ClearCase view (with the config spec I mention in my answer)?

Comment: VonC, I stopped working on this for a while. Now that I came back, I asked around here and it looks like the UCM component was not created with the right options. So since figuring out UCM was taking longer than expected, we will continue working under baseCC only, and postpone our involvement with UCM until we are better equipped to handle it.  In the meantime, thank you much for the help you provided.

Comment: @falconK: sure, but if you have any question on UCM, ask them there. With me, you *are* perfectly equipped ;) In the meantime, I have edited this answer to include your findings.